# How to improve unit test migration setup with Django?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, migration

I have created a Django project, which has more than 150 migration files. While running the unit tests, the setup itself is very much time consuming because Django first drops the database and creates a new test database and runs all migrations.

I have tried using `--keepdb` flag, but with this approach the problem is that ensuring the base setup is clean is not guaranteed.

One approach I can think of is using the `--keepdb` flag along with 2 additional steps-

- Before starting test, drop database, re-create from a database dump. Which will be way faster than running the migrations
- Run tests with [--keepdb flag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-keepdb)

Is there any other approach we can take to reduce the total setup time?

Comment: Perhaps you should [squash your migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations)?

Comment: `--keepdb` will keep the database, but will not retain anything you create/update/delete in the tests

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `pytest-django`, you may use `--no-migrations` flag to disable `migrations`. `pytest` will try to inspect the models and create `database` on that basis.

See [pytest-django-documentation](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#no-migrations-disable-django-migrations) for more details.

If you're using the inbuilt django's test command, you can add a `setting` to disable migrations.

```py
# settings.py

class DisableMigrations:
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return True

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return 'notmigrations'

MIGRATION_MODULES = DisableMigrations()
```

The above suggestion for on django's test-suite is based on [NotSqrt's gist](https://gist.github.com/NotSqrt/5f3c76cd15e40ef62d09).